# How to automatically start an interactive session when an error strikes?

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, compiler-errors, interactive

I usually run my scripts from the terminal like:

```
python script.py
```

Sometimes the code is running for long time and suddenly an error arises and stops the ongoing run. Instead of just stopping the run, is it possible to automatically enter to an interactive session at the point where the error happened? This would be of great use to debugging.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Take a look at [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), the Python debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue a time ago by using:

```
from IPython import embed
...code...
embed() # Code will enter interactive session at this line
...code...
```

Also, the use of `try:` and `except:` has been very useful.